# How to close spring integration channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have project with Spring Integration and input/output channels. The problem is in the last piece of config

```
 <int:transformer id="testTransformer"  input-channel="inChannel" method="processor"
        output-channel="outChannel">
            <bean class="someClass"/>
        </int:transformer>
```

It gives me an error

```
failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: No reply produced by handler 'testTransformer', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true
```

I understand that it's about my outputChannel is not initialized, so how correctly make program finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No reply produced by handler 'testTransformer', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true

That means that the `transformer` component is strictly request-reply and it definitely has to return something.

That's no the problem of your configuration, but your logic in the `someClass.processor()` method. Reconsider it to return anything valuable instead of `null`.

If `null` is possible by your logic and you manage it somehow in your flow, consider to switch to the `service-activator`. This one isn't so strict for its reply and allow to return `null`. But at the same time you should bear in mind that the flow stops exactly here. The `null` is invalid for messaging and is an indicator do stop processing because nothing what is `payload` any more.